# Inline Nav Bar Condense to a Drop-Down Block Nav Via a Font Button

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive, portrait

I'm creating a site for an artist friend of mine (kouroshesfandiari.com) and having trouble with the responsive navigation. On desktops and tablets in landscape mode I want a horizontal (inline) navigation, and for cell phones in portrait mode (upright) I want the three-line button icon to reveal a block-style navigation when hovered or tapped.

I used icomoon's app to install a tiny font file for the three-line icon, and using an orientation:portrait media query allows me to provide different functionality for cell phones. However, it seems that no matter what I change in the nav CSS or its portrait media query, the functionality isn't desired.

If I get it to look the way I want on cell phones, the nav remains a block for tablet and desktop sizes. If I get the nav inline and appearing how I want it for tablets and desktops, it throws everything off for the cell phone view. A better approach would be greatly appreciated. It seems a ton of sites use this type of responsive navigation now, but I'm unable to find resources describing how to do it.

**The HTML:**

```
<nav><!-- Responsive Navigation Menu -->
    <ul>
        <li><span class="icon-menu4"></span>


            <ul>
                <li class="hvr-rectangle-out"><a href="#">Pen & Ink Art</a></li>
                <li class="hvr-rectangle-out"><a href="#">3D Printed Art</a></li>
                <li class="hvr-rectangle-out"><a href="#">Merchandise</a></li>
                <li class="hvr-rectangle-out"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li class="hvr-rectangle-out"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**And the CSS:**

```
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 75%;
    right: 0%;
    bottom: 5%;
    left: 0%;
    padding: 40px;
}

header h1 {
    font-size: 4em;
    color: #FAF7F7;
    margin-top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 40px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

nav ul ul, nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 40px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

@media only screen and (orientation:portrait) {


    @font-face {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot?hnrm6o');
    src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefixhnrm6o') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.woff?hnrm6o') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.ttf?hnrm6o') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.svg?hnrm6o#icomoon') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    }

    [class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
        font-family: 'icomoon';
        speak: none;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        text-transform: none;
        line-height: 1;

    /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    }

    .icon-menu4:before {
        content: "\e9c0";
        color: white;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        padding: 0.25em;
        border: 2px solid white;
        border-radius: 0.15em;
    }




    nav ul ul {
        display: none;
        width: 11em;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        border-radius: 0.5em;
        position: absolute;
        top: -6.5em;
        right: -2em;
    }

    nav ul li:hover > ul, nav ul li ul:hover > ul, .icon-menu4:hover > ul {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this to get back inline menu in 

desktop

 @media screen and (mim-width: 750)
 {
    nav ul li
 {
   display: inline-block! important;
  }
  }

  Please don't use hover effect in.     

  mobile Screen
  And write perfect media query for.   

  mobile. View like

  @media screen and (max-width: 749)
  {
  }
```

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't work for me. I appreciate your feedback, though. I find that (orientation:portrait) is a better way of targeting mobile, because many mobile screens today are extremely large. For instance, my own phone's screen is 1440 x 2560 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (mim-width: 750px)
 {
    nav ul li
 {
   display: inline-block! important;
  }
  }
```

Comment: Ibrahim - that is the same answer you initially provided. As I said, unfortunately this did not work.